# Excel data doesn't appear, in the Excel Web Access

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, excel, excel-services

I've added an Excel Web part into my page. I did check out this excel workbook.  But,  when I want to run my page , I'm getting as follows error. Also,when I want to open xslx file in my desktop, the file doesn't open. Do I need to save in another format the file?

What is the reason for this? What should I do?
Thanks for advice.

[image]

Comment: What does the ULS log say?

Comment: I'm searching error id in logs, but I'm not finding this id. How can I search this error in logs file? @user19952

Comment: Set the logs to real time feed and try to recreate the error you had again to see what it logs.

Comment: Also, can it be that the file is corrupt? Does it involve any macros? If you cant open it on your desktop i think it's more a problem with the file then SharePoint.

Comment: Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80004005.                    Spent 0 ms to bind -1 byte file stream 1d76be9c-b67e-c067-e92a-0441379621f5                                                Failure when fetching document. 0x80070012 1d76be9c-b67e-c067-e92a-0441379621f5                                        SharePoint Foundation  Micro Trace    uls4 Medium   @user19952

Comment: How can I save this file to open via SharePoint? @user19952

Comment: Go to the files document location in sharepoint, click the three dots to the right of the filename, and then the three dots again to the right to "follow" and then from the menu select "download a copy."

Comment: Why should I do this? Sorry, I'm not understanding. @user19952

Comment: I thought you asked how to save the file from sharepoint..

Comment: No. I'm uploading normal xlsx file.But it isn't opening.Should I save this file to another format? @user19952

Comment: Does any other excel file work to open?

Comment: I'm uploading xslx file in desktop. It is saving as xls file. Then when I want to open this file it says "Windows can't open this type of file (.xls)" and I'm replacing this format as xslx but it is saving as notepad.Because of this I'm not opening xlsx file @user19952